# Plesk adding a crontask for every minute

Tags: cron, plesk, plesk-onyx

I want to have a crontask that executes every minute.
However in plesk you can only set a crontask every hour and the minute to execute it.

You can however choose to do this with a workaround.
From the Plesk manual I found : **https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004281794-How-to-create-a-scheduled-task-to-fetch-URL-every-15-seconds**

And they noted the following code :

**for i in {1..4}; do curl --silent "http://example.com" &>/dev/null; sleep 15; done**

However I am a bit afraid of using this code.
My guess to make a script execute every minute would be like:

**for i in {1..4}; do curl --silent "http://example.com/myscript.php" &>/dev/null; sleep 60; done**

But what scares me a bit is : **/dev/null**
I am not a unix guru at all but to my knowing /dev/null is the trashbin.

And what does 1..4 do?
Looks to me like it repeats itself only 4 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-Run a command : Fetch a URL

-Url : http://example.com/myscript.php

-Run : Cron Style * * * * *

Your URL will be fetch every minute

Comment: I know that they recommend people to stay away from thank you messages etc etc. But the only way of showing gratitude is to write it down. So thanks a million!!!!!

Tested it and it works!